# Report nickname instead of primary email for sso?

Tags: google, google-workspace, openid, stack-exchange

I use google apps for domains, the free version, I like to have my accounts setup with nicknames so I can filter off spam services.

E.g. my primary email is me@domain.com

I have the following nicknames

```
facebook@domain.com  facebook
twitter@domain.com   twitter
forumx@domain.com    forumx
```

This means I can tell, if I get a lot of spam to my forumx nickname then obviously that site has sold my details, or is displaying it somewhere, either way, I can setup a filter to block all email to that nickname.

My next question is SSO (e.g. the stackexchange network).

Can I set it up so I can choose what nickname to give to the site?

I know I could set it up with different accounts and forward the emails, but I would rather use nicknames and just have one username/password!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Stack Exchange support issue. Such questions should be asked at [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3):

You can "nickname" your email using [plus-sign addressing (plus-sign suffixing)](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12096?hl=en).

So, for instance you can sign up using these emails:

```
me+facebook@example.net
me+twitter@example.net
me+forumx@example.net
```

And they will all be delivered to `me@example.net`, providing that you are using GMail. This will allow you to keep one username and password, in your case the Google Apps account.

You can then analyze the headers of the mail for the `To:` field to see where the mail is going to, and in fact you can also create filters so that, for instance, all mail sent to `me+facebook@example.net` gets applied a label and is automatically marked as read and archived.

Now keep in mind that some sites do not validate email addresses properly. Despite the fact that the `+` character is permitted in email addresses in accordance to the RFC specification, some web forms consider it to be invalid. Since you mentioned that you're using Google Apps, I found an article on [using a "router user" to do *minus suffixing*](http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/automatic-disposable-email-addresses-for-google-apps-611.html). I can't test it out because I don't have Google Apps myself, but it seems pretty credible.

As for choosing which alias to give to a site, I don't think that is possible if you sign into the site *using Google*, but it is possible if you sign into the site using true OpenID. You can create an account at myOpenID and add all of your email aliases as personas of your OpenID, which you can choose when using it to sign into an OpenID-enabled site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple nicknames or email aliases via the admin control panel for any user or primary email address.

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33327

Comment: I am aware you can do that, that is what I am doing, however I am not happy with not being able to choose which nickname to show when signing up for a site via openID.